# os.startfile strange behaviour

Tags: python-3.x, windows, filepath

I'm receiving a string from a web extension. The string is a local file path, and I'm trying to open the filepath using the default OS setting for whatever that may be.

edit: Sorry! The question is: how can I successfully open the given path with the OS default app?

The filepath is initially a string formatted as below:

```
'file:///C:/Test/File/Path.docx'
```

WEIRD THINGS!

1. If Word is already open, it works fine.
2. If Word isn't already open, the blue Word "launching" screen shows for a split second then disappears (crashes, as subsequent attempts show the "start word in safe mode?" dialog for a split second instead).
3. It won't work *at all* unless I use "os.startfile" twice *specifically* as written. One outside a try statement, one inside. Any other combo won't work.
4. From IDLE, it works 100% of the time with just one "os.startfile" call.

I've also tried to use subprocess.check_call, but that fails to launch anything at all.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import json
import struct
import re, subprocess, os

def read_thread_func(queue):
  while 1:
    text_length_bytes = sys.stdin.buffer.read(4)

    if len(text_length_bytes) == 0:
      sys.exit(0)

    text_length = struct.unpack("i", text_length_bytes)[0]
    text = sys.stdin.read(text_length)
    data = json.loads(text)
    fileStr = data['url']
    filePath = re.sub('file:\/{1,3}','',fileStr)
    filePath = filePath.replace("/","\\")
    filePath = os.path.normpath(filePath)
    os.startfile(filePath)
    try:
      os.startfile(filePath)
    except AttributeError:
      "nothing to see here"
    sys.exit(0)

def Main():
  read_thread_func(None)
  sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  Main()
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: What happens if you use `subprocess.run(r'"{}"'.format(filePath), shell=True)` instead of `os.startfile`?

Comment: @ErykSun that works! Thank you :) was using 3.4 so upgraded to 3.8 for .run to work, but no issues after that

Comment: Also try an explicit action, such as `os.startfile(filePath, 'open')`. By default `startfile` calls WINAPI `ShellExecuteW` with whatever is the default action for a filetype. Otherwise, my guess is that it works via CMD because the shell calls the more-configurable `ShellExecuteExW` function with a few extra flags, which may make a difference in this case.